# Is it possible to connect via ip address only (teradata, jdbc)? java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, teradata

In my java application, I need to connect to a teradata database.

```
String DB_URL = "jdbc:teradata://***.***.***.***,tmode=ANSI,charset=UTF8";
String USERNAME = "***";
String PASSWORD = "***";
con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
```

When I try to connect I get a java.net.UnknownHostException.
Do I need to specify a hostname to connect to a teradata sql server? At the moment, I am only using the ip address.

Comment: Well, you can set the name in your lmhosts file too.

Comment: IP Addresses often change during platform upgrades. Hostnames typically persist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection URL should end the hostname part with `/` as far as I'm aware

`jdbc:teradata://***.***.***.***/tmode=ANSI,charset=UTF8`

Comment: Thank you! I will try this tomorrow.